# Foreach loop between two lists

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\firstlist{0,1,2}
\def\secondlist{0,1,2}

\newcommand{\testa}{
 \foreach \x/\y in {\firstlist/\secondlist} {
    \draw(0,\x)--(1,\y);
    }
}

\newcommand{\testb}{
 \foreach \x/\y in {0/0,1/1,2/2} {
    \draw(0,\x)--(1,\y);
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\testa
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I make the output of the `\testa` command equal to the output of the `\testb` command?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx!  This is a nice minimal example. I think you want to have another picture with `\testb` in it though, right?

Comment: @AlanMunn yes, to see the difference between the outputs. `\testb` is the desired output.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a very simple solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\firstlist{0,1,2}
\def\secondlist{0,1,2}

\newcommand{\testa}{
  \foreach \x [count=\c,evaluate=\c as \y using {{\secondlist}[\c-1]}]  in \firstlist {
    \draw(0,\x)--(1,\y);
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\testa
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

An extended solution defining the new style `parallel foreach`. You can use multiple parallel lists:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfset{
  foreach/parallel foreach/.style args={#1in#2via#3}{evaluate=#3 as #1 using {{#2}[#3-1]}},
}

\def\firstlist{0,1,2,10,11}
\def\secondlist{0,1,2,10,11}
\def\thirdlist{1,2,10,11,0}

\newcommand{\testa}{
  \foreach \x [count=\c,
  parallel foreach=\y in \secondlist via \c,
  parallel foreach=\z in \thirdlist via \c]
  in \firstlist
  {
    \node[left] at (0,\x) {\x};
    \draw(0,\x)--(1,\y);
    \draw[red](0,\x)--(1,\z);
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\testa
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both methods use the *array* features of pgfmath: they evaluate each element as a math formula. If you want string elements, use quotes (`"..."`).

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfset{
  foreach/parallel foreach/.style args={#1in#2via#3}{
    evaluate=#3 as #1 using {{#2}[#3-1]}
  },
}

\def\firstlist{0,1,2,10,11}
\def\secondlist{0,1,2,10,11}
\def\thirdlist{1,2,10,11,0}
\def\fourthlist{"label a","label b","label c","label $\delta$","label e"}
\newcommand{\testa}{
  \foreach \x [count=\c,
  parallel foreach=\y in \secondlist via \c,
  parallel foreach=\z in \thirdlist via \c,
  parallel foreach=\lab in \fourthlist via \c]
  in \firstlist
  {
    \node[left] at (0,\x) {\lab};
    \draw(0,\x)--(1,\y);
    \draw[red](0,\x)--(1,\z);
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\testa
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if element of `secondlist` is of more than one character!

Comment: @taninamdar Both solution may use `{0,1,2,10,11}` (as in my second edited example). If you want string elements, use quotes `"..."` (as in my third example).

Answer (score 10):

You can count how many elements there are in one of the arrays and use that number as the foreach limit. Then every spin accesses one element of the arrays;

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\def\firstlist{{0,1,2}} % <== Notice the double brace for array notation
\def\secondlist{{0,1,2}}

\newcommand{\testa}{
\pgfmathdim{\firstlist}%Get the number of elements in array
  \foreach \x in {0,...,\numexpr\pgfmathresult-1\relax}{%array index starts from zero
    \draw(0,{array(\firstlist,\x)})--(1,{array(\secondlist,\x)});
    }
}

\newcommand{\testb}{
 \foreach \x/\y in {0/0,1/1,2/2} {
    \draw(0,\x)--(1,\y);
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\testa
\begin{scope}[shift={(2,0)}] %Test the result with \testb next to it
\testb
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I'm not so sure you want to do it. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\def\xforeach#1#{\xforeachaux{#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xforeachaux}{mm}
 {
  \carlitos_xforeach:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_carlitos_xf_first_seq
\seq_new:N \l_carlitos_xf_second_seq
\seq_new:N \l_carlitos_xf_list_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \carlitos_xforeach:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_carlitos_xf_list_seq
  \__carlitos_split:n { #2 }
  \seq_mapthread_function:NNN
   \l_carlitos_xf_first_seq
   \l_carlitos_xf_second_seq
   \__carlitos_xf_additem:nn
  \__carlitos_xf_do:nx { #1 } { \seq_use:Nn \l_carlitos_xf_list_seq { , } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__carlitos_split:n #1
 {
  \__carlitos_split_aux:w #1 \q_stop
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__carlitos_split_aux:w #1/#2 \q_stop
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nno \l_carlitos_xf_first_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_set_split:Nno \l_carlitos_xf_second_seq { , } { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__carlitos_xf_additem:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_carlitos_xf_list_seq { #1/#2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__carlitos_xf_do:nn #1 #2
 {
  \foreach #1 { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nno }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__carlitos_xf_do:nn { nx }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{tikz}

\def\firstlist{0,1,2}
\def\secondlist{0,1,2}

\newcommand{\testa}{
 \xforeach \x/\y in {\firstlist/\secondlist} {
    \draw(0,\x)--(1,\y);
    }
}

\newcommand{\testb}{
 \foreach \x/\y in {0/0,1/1,2/2} {
    \draw(0,\x)--(1,\y);
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\testa
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
\testb
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A completely different implementation, where you don't even need `\x/\y`; it supports up to three slash separated arguments, which can be either comma separated lists (spaces are ignored before and after the commas) or macros expanding to comma separated lists.

Each cycle in the foreach loop is performed using the second argument, which uses `#1`, `#2` and `#3` to denote the current list element. The number of cycles is determined by the first list.

Probably a better error recovery should be provided if the given items are more than three, but this is left as an exercise.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\Xforeach}{mm}
 {
  \carlitos_Xforeach:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__carlitos_Xf_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l__carlitos_Xf_output_seq
\seq_new:N \l__carlitos_Xf_lista_seq
\seq_new:N \l__carlitos_Xf_listb_seq
\seq_new:N \l__carlitos_Xf_listc_seq
\tl_new:N \l__carlitos_Xf_tmp_tl
\int_new:N \l__carlitos_Xf_cycle_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \carlitos_Xforeach:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__carlitos_Xf_input_seq { / } { #1 }
  \seq_clear:N \l__carlitos_Xf_output_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__carlitos_Xf_input_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:No \l__carlitos_Xf_output_seq { ##1 }
   }
  \int_case:nnF { \seq_count:N \l__carlitos_Xf_input_seq }
   {
    { 1 } { \__carlitos_Xf_one:n   { #2 } }
    { 2 } { \__carlitos_Xf_two:n   { #2 } }
    { 3 } { \__carlitos_Xf_three:n { #2 } }
   }
   {
    Only~one,~two~or~three!
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__carlitos_Xf_one:n #1
 {
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__carlitos_Xf_output_seq \l__carlitos_Xf_tmp_tl
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__carlitos_Xf_first_seq { , } \l__carlitos_Xf_tmp_tl
  \cs_set_protected:Npn \__carlitos_Xf_loop:n ##1 { #1 }
  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \__carlitos_Xf_loop:n { x }
  \int_zero:N \l__carlitos_Xf_cycle_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__carlitos_Xf_first_seq
   {
    \int_incr:N \l__carlitos_Xf_cycle_int
    \__carlitos_Xf_loop:x { \seq_item:Nn \l__carlitos_Xf_first_seq { \l__carlitos_Xf_cycle_int } }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__carlitos_Xf_two:n #1
 {
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__carlitos_Xf_output_seq \l__carlitos_Xf_tmp_tl
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__carlitos_Xf_first_seq { , } \l__carlitos_Xf_tmp_tl
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__carlitos_Xf_output_seq \l__carlitos_Xf_tmp_tl
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__carlitos_Xf_second_seq { , } \l__carlitos_Xf_tmp_tl
  \cs_set_protected:Npn \__carlitos_Xf_loop:nn ##1 ##2 { #1 }
  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \__carlitos_Xf_loop:nn { xx }
  \int_zero:N \l__carlitos_Xf_cycle_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__carlitos_Xf_first_seq
   {
    \int_incr:N \l__carlitos_Xf_cycle_int
    \__carlitos_Xf_loop:xx
     { \seq_item:Nn \l__carlitos_Xf_first_seq { \l__carlitos_Xf_cycle_int } }
     { \seq_item:Nn \l__carlitos_Xf_second_seq { \l__carlitos_Xf_cycle_int } }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__carlitos_Xf_three:n #1
 {
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__carlitos_Xf_output_seq \l__carlitos_Xf_tmp_tl
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__carlitos_Xf_first_seq { , } \l__carlitos_Xf_tmp_tl
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__carlitos_Xf_output_seq \l__carlitos_Xf_tmp_tl
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__carlitos_Xf_second_seq { , } \l__carlitos_Xf_tmp_tl
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__carlitos_Xf_output_seq \l__carlitos_Xf_tmp_tl
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__carlitos_Xf_third_seq { , } \l__carlitos_Xf_tmp_tl
  \cs_set_protected:Npn \__carlitos_Xf_loop:nnn ##1 ##2 ##3 { #1 }
  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \__carlitos_Xf_loop:nnn { xxx }
  \int_zero:N \l__carlitos_Xf_cycle_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__carlitos_Xf_first_seq
   {
    \int_incr:N \l__carlitos_Xf_cycle_int
    \__carlitos_Xf_loop:xxx
     { \seq_item:Nn \l__carlitos_Xf_first_seq { \l__carlitos_Xf_cycle_int } }
     { \seq_item:Nn \l__carlitos_Xf_second_seq { \l__carlitos_Xf_cycle_int } }
     { \seq_item:Nn \l__carlitos_Xf_third_seq { \l__carlitos_Xf_cycle_int } }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\def\firstlist{0,1,2}
\def\secondlist{0,1,2}
\def\thirdlist{a,b,c}

\Xforeach{\firstlist}{--#1-- }

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Xforeach{\firstlist/\secondlist}{\draw(0,#1)--(1,#2);}
\end{tikzpicture}\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Xforeach{0,1,2/\secondlist}{\draw(0,#1)--(1,#2);}
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\Xforeach{\firstlist/\secondlist/\thirdlist}{#1/#2/#3 }

\Xforeach{\firstlist/\secondlist/\thirdlist}{#1/#2/#3 }

\Xforeach{\firstlist/0,1,2/a,b,c}{#1/#2/#3 }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you managed to scare me :)

Comment: @Carlitos It just shows that keeping your proposed syntax is not really easy. I tried thinking to a better syntax, but it was too late in the night. Stay focused.

Comment: Well, in the end I discarded the list thing and opted for a completely different approach, since my real world problem was actually more complicated than that in the MWE.

Answer (score 7):

You could always "roll your own" solution, but it would require considerable work to make it look as nice as `\foreach`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\def\attxt{@}
\long\def\frch#1#2#3{\long\def\frchaction##1##2{#3}%
\def\lsta{}\def\lstb{}%
\edef\lst{#1,@,/#2,@,}\expandafter\@frch\lst\@}
\def\@frch#1,#2/#3,#4\@{%
\def\tmpa{#1}\def\tmpb{#3}%
\ifx\tmpa\attxt%
  \ifx\tmpb\attxt%
  \else%
    \def\lstb{#3}\frchaction{\lsta}{#3}\@frch @,/#4,\@%
  \fi%
\else%
  \ifx\tmpb\attxt%
    \def\lsta{#1}\frchaction{#1}{\lstb}\@frch#2/@,\@%
  \else%
    \def\lsta{#1}\def\lstb{#3}\frchaction{#1}{#3}\@frch#2/#4\@%
  \fi%
\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\frch{0,1,2}{0,1,2}{ \draw (0,#1) -- (1,#2); }
\frch{0,1,2}{0,1,2,3,4,5}{ \draw (2,#1) -- (3,#2); }
\frch{0,1,2,3,4,5}{0,1,2}{ \draw (4,#1) -- (5,#2); }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]