\foreach loop over a \def'd list defined with \foreach
I'd like to \define a list using \foreach, then use that in another \foreach, like this:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\coords{\foreach \x in {1,...,10} \foreach \y in {1,...,10} {(\x,\y)}}
    
    \foreach \coord in \coords
    {
      \draw \coord node {A};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I would expect this to be equivalent to:
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,10} \foreach \y in {1,...,10}
    {
      \draw (\x,\y) node {A};
    }  
\end{tikzpicture}

But while the second one produces a 10x10 grid of As, as expected, the first version produces a single A.

As far as TeX is concerned, the cycle you try to do has a single item. If you try
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\coords{\foreach \x in {1,...,10} \foreach \y in {1,...,10} {(\x,\y)}}

  \foreach \coord in \coords {
    \show\coord
    \draw \coord node {A};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

you'll see on the console
> \coord=macro:
->\foreach \x in {1,...,10} \foreach \y in {1,...,10} {(\x ,\y )}.

which definitly isn't a coordinate pair. Apparently, given such an input you get the same as
\dfraw (1,1) (1,2) [...] (10,10) node {A};

Let's try.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\coords{\foreach \x in {1,2} \foreach \y in {1,2} {(\x,\y)}}

  \foreach \coord in \coords {
    \draw \coord node {A};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}}
\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (1,1) (1,2) (2,1) (2,2) node {A};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}

Yes, that's it!

With \def\coords{\foreach ...} you don't build a list of coordinates.
You could do
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \gdef\coords{\csname @gobble\endcsname}
  \foreach \x in {1,...,10} \foreach \y in {1,...,10} {\xdef\coords{\coords,(\x,\y)}}
  \foreach \coord in \coords {
    \draw \coord node {A};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

I don't see any advantage over
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw \foreach \x in {1,...,10} \foreach \y in {1,...,10} {(\x,\y) node {A}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



"I don't see any advantage" well this is extracted from something larger, where I want to iterate in parallel over this list of coordinates and a flat list of items to put there instead of A. I'm trying to use parallel foreach from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193943/2113, hence the need to define \coords.

I don't know yet whether I will be able to accept this -- it seems to interact weirdly with other looping constructs supposedly defined over lists, see my follow-up question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/729920/2113.
