Parallel foreach over a list of coordinates and a list of items
I'm trying to apply the parallel foreach idea from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193943/2113 to pair up a list of coordinates with a (potentially shorter) list of items. The answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/729882/2113 showed me how to put my coordinates into something I can foreach over normally, but it doesn't seem to work with parallel foreach.
Here's a small example of what I'm trying:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193943/2113
\pgfset{
  foreach/parallel foreach/.style args={#1in#2via#3}{evaluate=#3 as #1 using {{#2}[#3-1]}},
}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mygrid}[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/729882/2113
    \gdef\coords{\csname @gobble\endcsname}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,4} \foreach \y in {1,...,4} {\xdef\coords{\coords,(\x,\y)}}
    
    \foreach \cell [count=\c, parallel foreach=\coord in \coords via \c] in {#1}
    {
      \draw \coord node {\cell};
    }    
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\mygrid{1,2,3}
\end{document}

So I would like to compute the list of \coords first using two nested foreach loops, then I'd like to use the #1-length prefix of that to lay out the elements of #1. The above code fails with the unhelpful message:
! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.30 \mygrid{1,2,3}

If I try to \show the \coord as it iterates through the list, it shows complete gibberish:
> \coord=macro:
->1.

> \coord=macro:
->1.
                   
> \coord=macro:
->{{1}{2}}.

Contrast this with the non-parallel foreach version, which results in the expected (and desired!) output:
    \foreach \coord in \coords
    {
      \show\coord
    }

which results in:
> \coord=macro:
->(1,1).

> \coord=macro:
->(1,2).

...

> \coord=macro:
->(4,4).


You need to do \xdef\coords{\coords,"(\x,\y)"} in the preparation loop because the array syntax {#2}[#3-1] will evaluate each entry (which would actually consist of (\x and \y)) which you don't, you want just the "string".

@Qrrbrbirlbel I'd gladly accept that as an answer!

It's quite annoying that if I use "(\x,\y)" then in turn it seems to break something like \foreach \coord in \coords { \draw \coord node {A}; }...

I will add an answer later. I have an alternative for parallel foreach and also three other ways to place nodes in a grid without having to prepare the \coords list. Is there a greater goal for placing nodes in a grid?

@Qrrbrbirlbel my goal is to place the elements of #1 on a grid, filling left to right top to bottom as many elements as there are in #1, up to (in this minimal example) 4*4 of course.

The array syntax {#2}[#3-1] will (try) to evaluate each entry and also doesn't see the coordinates, so the entries are actually (1,, 1), (1, 2), and so on. Since you don't want to evaluate the entries and don't want to separate x and y values, you will need to use \xdef\coords{\coords,"(\x,\y)"} but then that list will not be usable by another \foreach loop – at least not without extra work.

I propose a different implementation of the parallel foreach key where the list is actually fed to a .list handler (which uses \foreach under the hood but doesn't group the iterations). This allows any \foreach list, including the ones with the coordinates and the ... syntax.
The entries will be stored away and each iteration saves the next one in the specified macro. The key sets up an internal counter so the third argument should not be specified.
I've added a \pgfforifparallel macro that tests whether the variable is actually specified (e.g. when you specify more main entries than parallel entries) and a \pgfforparalleldirect macro that gives you direct access to any of the entries (like an array).

That said, if you want a grid that wraps after four (or any number) entries, there are, in my opinion, much better solutions available:

\myGridF uses one loop over your list and calculates the needed x and y values.

\myGridC uses the same math but with the chains library.
As it is not depended on a loop, you don't actually need to place all nodes in a loop. You could just do
\node[on chain]{A};
\node[on chain]{17};
\node[on chain]{$\alpha$};

and they would all be placed at the correct position in the grid.

\myGridG uses the graphs library's grid placement strategy (which internally uses the same int/mod math).

\myGridCS uses a custom coordinate system grid cs:<i> which takes the number <i> and the grid cs wrap value to calculate the position.


As your original grid originally goes first upwards than to the right, I've implemented all these to do the same.
You can swap the functions around or negate their result to customize the directions and the order. For the graphs solution this is dictated by grow up and branch right.
Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\pgfset{
  foreach/@parallel foreach/.code={%
    \advance\c@pgf@counta1
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgf/foreach/parallel foreach/\pgffor@parallel@var-\the\c@pgf@counta}{#1}},
  foreach/parallel foreach/.code args={#1in#2}{%
    \c@pgf@counta=-1 \edef\pgffor@parallel@var{\expandafter\pgfutil@gobble\string#1}%
    \pgfset{foreach/@parallel foreach/.list/.expand once={#2}}% expand list-macro or first item
    \pgfqkeys{/pgf/foreach}{count=\pgffor@parallel@count from 0}%
    \pgfutil@append@tomacro\pgffor@assign@before@code{%
      \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgf/foreach/parallel foreach/\expandafter\pgfutil@gobble\string#1-\pgffor@parallel@count}{#1}%
    }}}
\newcommand*\pgfforifparallel[1]{%
  \pgfkeysifdefined{/pgf/foreach/parallel foreach/\expandafter\pgfutil@gobble\string#1-\pgffor@parallel@count}}
\newcommand*\pgfforparalleldirect[2]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/foreach/parallel foreach/#1-#2}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\mygrid}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/729882/2113
    \gdef\coords{\csname @gobble\endcsname}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,4} \foreach \y in {1,...,4} {\xdef\coords{\coords,(\x,\y)}}
    \foreach \coord in \coords % \coords is a proper list!
      \fill[blue!75] \coord circle[radius=1pt];
    \foreach \cell [count=\i, parallel foreach=\coord in \coords] in {#1}{
      \pgfforifparallel\coord{
        \path \coord node {\cell};
      }{% \coords had only sixteen entries … what now?
        \node[red, shift=\pgfforparalleldirect{coord}{\inteval{\i-17}}] at (.5, .5){\cell};
      }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand*\myGridF[2][4]{%
  \tikz
    \foreach[count=\i from 0, evaluate={\x=int(\i/#1);
                                        \y=mod(\i,#1);}] \v in {#2}
      \node at (\x, \y) {\v};}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\newcommand*\myGridG[2][4]{%
  \tikz\graph[grid placement, grow up, branch right, wrap after={#1}]
    {\foreach\cell in {#2}{\cell}};} % or subgraph I_n[V={#2}] with graphs.standard

\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\newcommand*\myGridC[2][4]{%
  \tikz[start chain=placed {at={({int((\tikzchaincount-1)/#1)},
                                 {mod(\tikzchaincount-1,#1)})}}]
    \foreach \cell in {#2}
      \node[on chain] {\cell};}

\tikzset{grid cs wrap/.initial=4}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{grid}{\pgfpointxy{int((#1)/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid cs wrap})}
                                              {mod(\i,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid cs wrap})}}
\newcommand*\myGridCS[2][4]{%
  \tikz[grid cs wrap={#1}]
    \foreach[count=\i from 0]\cell in {#2}
      \node at (grid cs:\i) {\cell};}
\begin{document}
\mygrid  { 1, ..., 32}
\myGridF {17, ..., 32}
\myGridG {33, ..., 48}
\myGridC {49, ..., 64}
\myGridCS{65, ..., 80}
\end{document}

Output


Holy... \myGridC is I think the one I love the most, because it means I can turn my whole thing into an environment inside which I can lay out as many nodes as I want, with as much other stuff in between as I want!
